# Linking External Static Libraries Independently with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, build

I am trying to add a manager to a subproject that uses an externally created static library. This library provides libcurl.a, libssl.a, and libcrypto.a.

Among the other libraries I am using, there is one that uses a different version of ssl and crypto. I want my code in the subproject to link independently with curl, ssl, crypto, and the external library, and then link the subproject to the main. The file structure and CMakeLists are as follows:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   ├── curl
│   ├── external_library
│   └── openssl
├── lib
│   └── static
│       ├── libcrypto.a
│       ├── libcurl.a
│       ├── libExternalLibrary.a
│       └── libssl.a
└── src
    ├── manager
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── manager.cpp
    │   └── manager.h
    └── main.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(Link_test VERSION 0.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_subdirectory(src/manager)

add_executable(Link_test src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Link_test manager)
```

src/manager/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(manager STATIC manager.cpp)

target_include_directories(manager PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(manager PRIVATE 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/static/libcurl.a
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/static/libssl.a
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/static/libcrypto.a
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/static/libExternalLibrary.a
)
```

When I build, I get the following error

```
LicenseService.cpp:(.text+0xc4f): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init'
...
```

Additionally, when using add_library with STATIC, I discovered that the libraries listed in target_link_libraries are also linked when the main is linked. This affects different versions of ssl and crypto used by other libraries. Changing it to SHARED resolves this issue, but I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: src/license/libmanager.so: undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init'
...
```

I am wondering if my requirements are impossible to meet or if there is another way to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "when using add_library with STATIC, I discovered that the libraries listed in target_link_libraries are also linked when the main is linked." - Actually, those libraries are not "also" linked to `main`, they are **only** linked to `main`. Creation of a static library (`manager` in your case) doesn't involve linking step at all. So, everything you specified in `target_link_libraries` for a static library is propagated to the consumer of that static library.